# ListView C# WPF Binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

So I have this code. I want to delete from database when I select a row in `ListView`.  My idea is to delete from table with selected ID.
I tried with `listViewScenarist.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0]` but the code doesn't recognize `SubItems[0]`. What can I do?

```
public class UserScenarist : Scenarist
{
    public int idScenarist { get; set; }
    public string numeScenarist { get; set; }
}

public void deleteScenarist(System.Windows.Controls.ListView listScenarist)
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.Scenarist WHERE idScenarist=@idScenarist", connection);
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(listScenarist.SelectedIndex);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idScenarist", listViewScenarist.SeletedItems[x].SubItems[0]);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Populate:

```
public void loadScenarist(System.Windows.Controls.ListView listScenarist)
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Scenarist ORDER BY idScenarist ASC", connection);

    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        listScenarist.Items.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {  
            List<UserScenarist> items = new List<UserScenarist>();
            items.Add(new UserScenarist() { idScenarist = Int32.Parse(dr["idScenarist"].ToString()), numeScenarist = dr["scenarist"].ToString() });
            //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(dr["idScenarist"].ToString());
            listScenarist.Items.Add(items);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried listViewScenarist.Items[x]  ??

Comment: @LeonardH I don't know how you populate you list but `SelectedItem(s)` should be of you item type so: `(listViewScenarist.SeletedItems[x] as UserScenarist).idScenarist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has very little to do with binding but your first problem is that every time you add `List<UserScenarist>`, with only one item, as an item.

Instead create one list, add items to that list and then set `ItemsSource` with that list.

```
var items = new List<UserScenarist>();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{  
    items.Add(new UserScenarist() { 
                 idScenarist = Int32.Parse(dr["idScenarist"].ToString()), 
                 numeScenarist = dr["scenarist"].ToString() 
             });
}
listScenarist.ItemsSource = items;
```

if you fix that as above then you can cast `SelectedItem(s)` as `UserScenarist`

```
var selectedId = (listViewScenarist.SeletedItem as UserScenarist).idScenarist;
```

or

```
var selectedId = (listViewScenarist.SeletedItems[x] as UserScenarist).idScenarist;
```

also, your code

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(listScenarist.SelectedIndex);
listViewScenarist.SeletedItems[x]
```

won't work and will, almost all the time, throw out of range exception. `SelectedIndex` is global for all items and will range from 0 to items count - 1. `SelectedItems` however will have only selected items so its length will range only from 0 to selected items count - 1. **You cannot use `SelectedIndex` to get items from `SelectedItems`**

Answer (score 0):

To find `idScenarist` you can just cast the `listViewScenarist.SelectedItem` to your `UserScenarist` model then get selected `idScenarist` like this:

```
int idScenarist = (listViewScenarist.SelectedItem as UserScenarist).idScenarist;
```

Then:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idScenarist", idScenarist);
```

Comment: Dont work..
ERROR  : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @LeonardH...You should first select an item in your `ListView` then call the `deleteScenarist` method.

Comment: @LeonardH...I don't know how you call the `deleteScenarist` method but I'm sure this code should works as you want.